# Why aren't the images in my flex column touching?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I want to have two columns two rows, with the first row with text in the first column, then an image in the second, and the second row with an image in the first column and text in the second.

I want the corners of the images to touch to create a perfect grid, and it's driving me crazy that no matter what I do they never touch.

**Here's the code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/zbqewcrx/

```
<body>
 
 <div>        
<div class="block reverse">
  <div class="block-info left">
    <div class="block-info-content">
      <div class="block-title">
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="block-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis tempus nibh. Sed eget lacinia lorem. Integer imperdiet sodales bibendum. Donec fermentum viverra orci, at scelerisque erat commodo sit amet. Nullam et blandit massa. Quisque gravida consectetur tristique. Sed eget tempor ante. Aliquam aliquet dolor porta suscipit elementum. Ut vel fringilla lacus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-photo">
    <div class="block-img first">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607028227034-f0378aa1bd2c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=735&q=80">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-photo">
    <div class="block-img">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607028227034-f0378aa1bd2c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=735&q=80">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="block-info right">
    <div class="block-info-content">
      <div class="block-title">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="block-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis tempus nibh. Sed eget lacinia lorem. Integer imperdiet sodales bibendum. Donec fermentum viverra orci, at scelerisque erat commodo sit amet. Nullam et blandit massa. Quisque gravida consectetur tristique. Sed eget tempor ante. Aliquam aliquet dolor porta suscipit elementum. Ut vel fringilla lacus.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  
</body>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0 20em;

}

h2, h3, h1, h4, p {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  line-height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
}

.block-info, .block-photo {
  width: 50%;

}


.block-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  object-fit: cover;
  
}
  
.block-info-content {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2em;
}

.block-text {
  padding-top: 2em;
}
</style>
```

screencap of the corners of the images in my code
[image]

In my website the corners are always almost touching but not quite there :(

Originally I had padding but I removed it (in classes .left, .right) and that made it better (the corners are almost touching now) but it's just that, almost.

Comment: Why do you have block-img height set to 600px instead of 100%?

Comment: 100% makes the image too tall for my taste, 600px makes it more on the square side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `line-height` property seems to be what is causing that small margin, you can fix it by moving the property to the class that contains the text

```css
.block {
  line-height: 0;
}

.block-info-content {
  line-height: 24px;
}
```